# Magento save Transaction ID and Customer Detail from Payment Gateway into Order Details

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order

I had used the following code to add attributes to the Order table:

```
<?php

$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

$attribute1 = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend_type' => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'Transaction ID',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'default' => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'new_transaction_id', $attribute1);

$attribute2 = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend_type' => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'Customer ID',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'default' => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'customer_id', $attribute2);

$attribute3 = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend_type' => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'MTID',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'default' => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'mt_id', $attribute3);

$attribute4 = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend_type' => 'text',
    'frontend_input' => 'text',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label' => 'MITEM',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'default' => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'mitem', $attribute4);

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

And to save the details I have used the below code, but nothing gets saved and I do not even get any error, I am unable to find the issue.

```
$order->setNewTransactionId($trx_id);
$order->setVleId($cust_id);
$order->setMtrxId($mtid);
$order->setMitem($mitem);
$order->save();
```

Could anyone please suggest what I have implemented wrong.

Comment: did you put code in try & catch

Comment: @ShaheerAli yes the code when saving transaction details is in try catch block

Comment: Try to check if you are getting correct order id: $order->getId() ?

Comment: After this installation do you see new columns in the sales_flat_order table?

Answer (score 1):

Can seem weird and maybe it's not the case but table structure is cached; this kind of caching is handled by `Zend_Cache` class which doesn't store data in `magedir/var/cache` but usually in `/tmp` folder.

Thus your table structure won't be updated until you remove all the `/tmp/zend*` files.

I'm assuming you use a *nix based OS.

Hope it helps.